# Why are my django model fields not working?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-models

I don't think that it is recognizing the existence of my fields. Here's my models.py:

```
from django.db.models import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms import *

class Stock(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=60)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

admin.site.register(Stock)
```

When I run it, I get this error: "portfolio.stock: "ordering" refers to "name", a field that doesn't exist." When I comment the meta function out and run it, it works fine until the admin site, where when I try to create a stock object, the fields don't show up.

I'm completely confused by what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your `*` imports.

`django.db.models.CharField` is being replaced by `django.forms.CharField`:

```
>>> from django.db.models import *
>>> CharField 
<class 'django.db.models.fields.CharField'>
>>> from django.forms import *
>>> CharField 
<class 'django.forms.fields.CharField'>
```

So, actually `name = CharField(max_length=60)` defines a form field instead of a model one - it breaks everything and makes this bug subtle.

---

Solution: remove unnecessary `forms` import and be explicit in your imports:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin


class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

admin.site.register(Stock)
```

Comment: Also note the `models.Model` and `models.Charf...` changes :p